# How can I draw a grid in matplotlib that is limited by the data points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a subplot in which I want to emphasize the data points by drawing grid-like lines that are parallel to the axis but only fill the space between the axis and data points (the normal grid goes beyond the data points).

I know that there are multiple ways to draw lines and rectangles in matplotlib. I could iterate over my data and just draw a rectangle for every data point that starts at (0, 0).
But I'd like to know if there is a way to do this more easily.

The normal grid:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN0bI.png

My desired grid:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEthY.png

EDIT:
Here is a stripped-down version of my code with all of my subplots I want to have a grid as I described it.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x_data1 = [1, 2, 5, 7, 20]
y_data1 = [5.20, 10.40, 26.00, 36.40, 104.00]

y_data2 = [3.7, 7.4, 18.5, 25.9, 74]

y_data3 = [8.95, 17.9, 44.75, 62.65, 179]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(12, 3), tight_layout=True, sharey="all")

ax[0].plot(x_data1, y_data1, marker="o")
ax[0].grid(which="major", linestyle="--", color="black", alpha=0.3)
ax[0].set_xticks(x_data1)
ax[0].set_yticks(y_data1)
ax[0].set_ylim(bottom=0)
ax[0].set_title("Multiplier: 5.2")

ax[1].plot(x_data1, y_data1,
           x_data1, y_data2, marker="o")
ax[1].set_title("Mult.: 5.2, Mult.: 3.7")

ax[2].plot(x_data1, y_data1,
           x_data1, y_data3, marker="o")
ax[2].set_title("Mult.: 5.2, Mult.: 8.95")

plt.show()
```

Comment: It would probably be easier to get help starting from your code. Perhaps you should include that in your question, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gridlines should always reach the axes, independent of the axes limits. So what you need is a line with one end defined in a blended coordinate system, with one coordinate being `0` in axes coordinates. The other end would be completely in data coordinates. A way to achieve this is with a `matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch

data_x = [1,2,5,7,20]
data_y = [5.2,10.40, 26.00, 36.40,104.00]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Create your own grid
for x,y in zip(data_x, data_y):
    cp1 = ConnectionPatch((x,0), (x,y), 
                         coordsA=ax.get_xaxis_transform(),
                         coordsB="data", axesA=ax, axesB=ax,
                         color='grey', linestyle='--', )
    cp2 = ConnectionPatch((0,y), (x,y), 
                         coordsA=ax.get_yaxis_transform(),
                         coordsB="data", axesA=ax, axesB=ax,
                         color='grey', linestyle='--')
    ax.add_patch(cp1)
    ax.add_patch(cp2)


plt.scatter(data_x, data_y, color='black')
plt.plot(data_x, data_y, color='black')

plt.margins(x=0, y=0)
plt.xticks(data_x)
plt.yticks(data_y)
plt.show()
```

The main difference of this code compared to the other answer is observable when interactively zooming or panning the plot.

[image]

Comment: This is the result I wanted! Seems like you can't really avoid a loop. Thank you very much

Comment: What is the purpose of "avoiding a loop"? (I mean sure you can tinker a code that avoids a loop, but that would require a callback on limits change events - so it would be doubly as long and doubly as hard to understand. Plus it would *probably* even be slower)

Comment: I'm not that experienced with matplotlib and so far I was able to adjust everything I want inside the arguments of matplotlib-functions / -methods. This is just the first thing I face where this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find an answer by using the grid function, but I generated the grid by a loop of plots. Here is my suggestion for a solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_x = [1,2,5,7,20]
data_y = [5.2,10.40, 26.00, 36.40,104.00]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Create your own grid
for x,y in zip(data_x, data_y):
    plt.plot([x,x,0], [0,y,y], color='grey', linestyle='--')

plt.scatter(data_x, data_y, color='black')
plt.plot(data_x, data_y, color='black')

plt.margins(x=0, y=0)
plt.xticks(data_x)
plt.yticks(data_y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This certainly works and is similar to what I would do but I would like to know if there is a way to do the same without a loop. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I could not find any other solution.

Comment: You need only one plot per line. I edited the code.